# Scroll UILabel with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
messageLabel.text = CONNECTED;
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[messageLabel sizeToFit];
self.TableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;
```

The last row of this code set `backgroundView` to my `UILabel` but it stays centered and if I scroll the table view, the message position stays fixed. How to solve this problem?
I want that the `UILabel` to follow the scroll event.

Comment: It's the cell that scroll not the tableView itself, put the label in a `UITAbleViewCell`

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Could you be more detailed ?
I am beginning with objective- C and already hate him!

Comment: Im trying to say that the background does not move its the cells that scroll, can you show an screenshot

Comment: Ok, sorry, I understand. But my problem is a little bit different. I want that the message "The list is empty" to follow the scroll event. For example: suppose that safari on your iphone notified you that "The server is unreachable" when you scroll the current page of safari, the message follow the scroll event.

Comment: So, in that case, you should create just 1 cell , which contains the label "The server is unreachable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your UILabel as a subview to your tableView and send it back.

```
[self.TableView addSubview:messageLabel];
[self.TableView sendSubviewToBack:messageLabel];
```

Now when you scroll the tableView, this view will also get scrolled.

**Other code enhancements** (Not related to the question)

You can initialize your label like this

```
UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply because it works! Another little question: how to put the message in the CENTER of the view? Thank you so much!

Comment: remove the sizeToFit method - Or else you need to place your label in center. Do this [messageLabel setFrame:CGRectOffset(messageLabel.bounds, CGRectGetMidX(self.TableView.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(self.TableView.bounds)/2, CGRectGetMidY(self.TableView.frame) - CGRectGetHeight(self.TableView.bounds)/2 )]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following tutorials of TableView:

swift: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

objective-c: http://www.makemegeek.com/uitableview-example-ios/

Basically,you should add your label inside a cell and it will work.